# I have an Italian EU passport that expires October 2017, and I am planning to move to Germany in May 2015, can I get an early renewal on my passport?

Tags: europe, passports, italy, italian-citizens

I am planning to move to Europe before the end of 2015 and wanted to know if it is possible for an early renewal of my passport. That way I don't have to stress about it for another ten years?

Comment: I changed your title to _I am planning to move to Germany_; otherwise some might be curious why you want to renew your passport which expires two years after your trip.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  If I were you, I would just renew the passport in October 2017.

Answer (score 5):

The concept of passport renewals in Italy was abolished and doesn't exist anymore. What happens now is that you get a brand new passport with a ten-year validity from the date of issue. Quoting from [the Italian Police website](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10301-Il_Rilascio/):

> Il passaporto è rilasciato ai cittadini italiani e ha durata decennale. Alla scadenza della validità, riportata all'interno del documento, non si rinnova ma si deve richiedere l'emissione di un nuovo passaporto.

See [my other answer on the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44750/22140) for more details.

Having said this, **you can obtain a new Italian passport at any moment you wish**, regardless of the expiry date.